# Jquery - Toggle mousedown event without destroying it in the dom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

**So on Friday I asked this question and it wasn't well written, let me explain this in better detail:**

So this might sound remedial, but I have this container that I include a mousedown event and all I want to do is toggle it without destroying the properties of it.

If it do :

```
 $("#div").unbind("mousedown")  // This will just destroy the event.
```

I was thinking I could move the event to a dom element that isn't being used? And then just switch it back when I'm done...

So this is whats happening :  I have a plugin lets just call it Vinny for now

```
  $("#div").vinny(settings);
```

vinny has a mousedown event that I want to enable/disable via a trigger.

I was thinking I would have a $fn.disableMouseDown function that could disable it, but was curious if theirs a way to unbind a mouseDown on the dom but not destroy it?

If you know of a quick way of doing it help me out! Thanks, Vinny

Comment: Forgot to mention! That the bind event is wrappend in an object 

So I have $("#div").plugin() 

inside of plugin i have the mousedown event

Comment: I think we will need more details if you need our help :)

Comment: What are you trying to toggle by invoking a mouse down?  Is this being done someplace else in the DOM?  You could just tell it to run the same function or something along those lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys thanks for all the ideas, but I kinda did a hacky way of approaching this.

I explainz:

So this plugin on the mousedown is binded in the plugin.init() and in their i defined a local function checks disableValue and in their I just check the dom for a  or  do a bool return and run that against the other function that was already present in exiting the mousedown event.

Make sense? I hope so too

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Put your command inside a function, so you can bind/unbind with one line only, i.e:

```
function some() {
    // some commands
}

$("#div").bind("mousedown", some);
$("#div").unbind("mousedown");
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to just use a named function, bind it when it's needed and unbind it when it's not:

```
function foo () { 
    // do something on mousedown
}

// When needed:
$("#div").bind("mousedown", foo);

// When not needed:
$("#div").unbind("mousedown", foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just stick an `if(toggle)` statement inside the event. Any reason you can't do that? (only thing i can think of is you wouldn't want to have the event being continually fired over and over, which makes sense - is that the case?)

Answer (score 0):

**here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/samccone/ENzyk/**

I think this is a simple and elegant solution